# "Slang" large numbers in php?

Tags: php

Something like this:

```
echo somefn(2800000000); // outputs '2,8B' for 2,8 billion
echo somefn(2000000); // outputs '2M' for 2 million
echo somefn(5400); // outputs '5,4K' for 5,400
echo somefn('blabla') // outputs 'blabla' as it is because it isn't a number
echo somefn(5) // outputs 5, nothing to simplify
```

I know it must be really easy code but I wonder if anyone else has something that accounts for maybe other cases that don't pop in my head right now.

**/Edit** I'm looking for something more in the lines of a generalized, built-in PHP function (or something close to that). Pretty much the same way `strtotime()` can handle things like "weeks" or "months".

Comment: "I know it must be really easy code", great please write it then. The *slang* seems arbitrary so with out a list of the rules what can one do?

Comment: Work out if you want to round your numbers or not, otherwise you'll have to take into account what is the smallest possible abbreviated version to reduce to without rounding information (eg number of trailing zeros)

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a code writing service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172661). Please define the problem you're trying to solve, post what you've written so far that isn't working, and explain how it's not working the way you want it to, and we'll try and help. We're not doing your work for you; if you need that, hire a consultant or contractor.

Comment: @Dagon that's what this question is for. The same way `strtotime` converts from generic stuff like "weeks" or "months" I thought there might be something close to a built-in conversion function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any off the shelf function you can call. Here's one possible solution:

```
function number_abbr($number) {
  if (!is_numeric($number) || $number < 1000)
    return $number;

  $postfix = array("K", "M", "B", "T");
  while ($number >= 1000 && count($postfix) > 0) {
    $number /= 1000;
    $append = array_shift($postfix);
  }

  // if the number is still greater than 1000...
  if ($number > 1000)
    return "a lot";

  // return the output
  return sprintf("%1.1f" . $append, $number);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work pretty nicely:

```
function somefn( $num) {
    if( !is_numeric( $num)) return $num;
    $num = floatval( $num);
    $suffix = '';
    if( $num / 1000000000 > 1) {
        $num = $num / 1000000000;
        $suffix = 'B';
    }
    elseif( $num / 1000000 > 1) {
        $num = $num / 1000000;
        $suffix = 'M';
    }
    elseif( $num / 1000 > 1) {
        $num = $num / 1000;
        $suffix = 'K';
    }
    return number_format( $num, 1, ',', ',') . ' ' . $suffix;
}
```

This outputs:

```
2,8 B
2,0 M
5,4 K
blabla
5,0
```

You can of course tweak it to precisely match the desired output. [Here is a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1rHxyP) showing it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Loop-free.

```
function abbr_number($size,$decimals=2,$sizes = array("","K","M","B","T")) {
    if(!is_numeric($size) || $size==0) return ($size); 
    if(!is_numeric($decimals) || $decimals<0) $decimals=2;

    $size=abs($size);
    $n = ($size/pow(1000,($i = floor(log($size, 1000)))))*
        (isset($sizes[$i])?1:pow(1000,$i-(count($sizes)-1)).end($sizes));

    return ($size<=0?'-':'').($size>0 ? round($n*pow(10,$decimals))/pow(10,$decimals):$n).
        (isset($sizes[$i])?$sizes[$i]:array_pop($sizes));
}

echo(implode('<br />',array(
    abbr_number(2800000000),
    abbr_number(2000000),
    abbr_number(5400),
    abbr_number('blabla'),
    abbr_number(5),
    abbr_number(pow(rand(),rand(1,5)))
)));
```